# List Item Selected property not firing click event handler

Tags: c#

I have two dropdown lists, `ddlPrimarySeries` and `ddlSecondarySeries`. I also have a button (`ImgBtnSeriesReversal`) in the middle of these dropdown lists that switches the selected values in the dropdown. This is the code that switches the selected items on the button click:

```
foreach (ListItem item in ddlPrimarySeries.Items)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Value) == intSecondarySeries)
    {
        item.Selected = true;
        break;
    }
}

foreach (ListItem item in ddlSecondarySeries.Items)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Value) == intPrimarySeries)
    {
        item.Selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

It loops through the list items and sees if the currently iterated item is equal to the selected item in the other dropdown and if so it selects it with `item.Selected = true` and then breaks. My issue is that when the values switch in the dropdowns the `ddlPrimarySeries_SelectedIndexChanged` and `ddlSecondarySeries_SelectedIndexChanged` events don't get fired. How can I accomplish this and have the event handlers fire when the values change?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (ListItem item in ddlPrimarySeries.Items)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Value) == intSecondarySeries)
    {
        item.Selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
***ddlPrimarySeries_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());***
foreach (ListItem item in ddlSecondarySeries.Items)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Value) == intPrimarySeries)
    {
        item.Selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
***ddlSecondarySeries_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());***
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have AutoPostBack set to true for the dropdown lists. By default it is false.

Comment: Yes AutoPostBack is true